# Stream CSV or TSV files

Tags: import, streams, csv-format

RAM limitations make import impractical for large CSV files. Is it possible to Stream CSV correctly?

```
str = OpenRead["EU.csv"];
Read[str, "CSV"]
```

> Read::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from EU.csv

```
Read@str
```

> Read::readt: Invalid input found when reading "lTid, cDealable, CurrencyPair, RateDateTime, RateBid, RateAsk" from EU.csv

```
Close@str
```

Here's the [CSV](http://juggernautmotorsports.ca/work/ratedata/2011/01%20January/EUR_USD_Week1.zip) file. Though I think it's properly formatted.

Comment: You sure it's RAM limitations? Or it's not the same file as the one you post. I have no problem at all importing your file, as expected given it's less than a MB in size…

Comment: Running on very light hardware :P. But that's a week of forex data that should be 4.9MB expanded. A lot of the CSVs are 4-10x that, so 20-50MB expanded.

Comment: @Mr.DemetriusMichael please add the CSV file to some permanent place like your question, it is missing. -1 until CSV back.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a function which may help:

```
Clear[readRows];
readRows[stream_, n_] :=
   With[{str = ReadList[stream, "String", n]},
      ImportString[StringJoin[Riffle[str, "\n"]], "Table"] /; str =!= {}];
readRows[__] := $Failed;
```

I tested on your file and it works all right (it may make sense to read rows in batches, this is much faster):

```
n=0;
str = OpenRead["C:\\Temp\\EUR_USD_Week1.csv"];
While[readRows[str, 1000] =!= $Failed, n++];
Close[str];
n

(*  82   *)
```

By the way, speaking of practicality of `Import` - I agree, but do read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525782/import-big-files-arrays-with-mathematica/7527064#7527064) - it is based on the same idea as above code, and makes importing whole files quite practical IMO. In particular, using the `readTable` function from there, I get your file read in its entirety under 3 seconds on my machine:

```
In[64]:= readTable["C:\\Temp\\EUR_USD_Week1.csv",2000]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
Out[64]= {2.4775391,{{lTid,cDealable,CurrencyPair,RateDateTime,RateBid,RateAsk},
  <<81172>>,{1385715072,D\[Ellipsis] SD,2011-01-07,\[Ellipsis] }}}
```

with a very decent memory usage:

```
MaxMemoryUsed[]

(* 71652808 *)
```

meaning 50 Mb of net usage (when you subtract the startup memory usage) - for this particular example. You can tweak the second parameter to trade run-time for memory efficiency. See the linked post for more details.

Comment: beautiful, thanks. Not sure why Mathematica doesn't improve it's memory usage.

Comment: @Mr.DemetriusMichael I think it will, in time. The current `Import`-`Export` framework is fairly new, quite natural that it has rough corners. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

#### Summary

This is generalized piece of code for reading **FAST** rows terminated with a newline from a **CSV** or **TSV** text stream with **UTF8 encoding**.

You may specify options for the **filetype**, the **starting** and **ending** line number, as well as a string to search for a position in the file (**find**). By default the result includes the **header** which can be omitted.

The **import** option (True/False) controls whether there is going to be a post-processing of the rows read from the file with the ImportString function. This is slower than the ReadList with user specified **types** option or with **import->False**.

If you want to read only the header of the file then specify **start->0, end->0**

#### Code

```
null[_String] := Null
countLines = Length@ReadList[#, null@String, NullRecords -> True] &;

ClearAll[readRows];
Options[readRows]={filetype->"CSV",start->0,end->-1, types->{}, import->True, find->"", header->True};
readRows[fname_String?FileExistsQ,OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[
{txtstrm, ftype,typesval,impmethod,
 startLine,endLine,line1,str, 
 hdr, hdrflag, body, bodyImport, blnk},

(* Blank function for skipping word separators, e.g. commas *)
blnk[]=blnk[Character];
blnk[_String]=Sequence[];

(* Get Option Values *)
startLine=OptionValue[start];endLine=OptionValue[end];
ftype=OptionValue[filetype];typesval=OptionValue[types];
impmethod=OptionValue[import];str=OptionValue[find];
hdrflag=OptionValue[header] ;

(* Open Stream *)
txtstrm=OpenRead[fname];

(* Process Header, i.e. first line *)
line1 = ReadList[txtstrm,Record,1][[1]];
Which[
 ftype=="CSV", hdr = StringSplit[line1,","],
 ftype=="TSV", hdr = StringSplit[line1,"\t"],
 True, Abort[] ];

(* If user has not specified any types for ReadLine, types\[Rule]{} *)
If[Length@typesval==0,typesval= Riffle[Table[Word,Length@hdr],blnk[]]];

(* If user has not specified the line to end reading *)
If[endLine==-1,endLine=countLines@fname];

(* If user specified to start reading the text stream from a specific line *)
If [startLine!=0,Skip[txtstrm,Record,startLine]];

(* If user specified a string to find in a file *)
If[str!="",Find[txtstrm,str]];

(* Check the import option for post-processing each row with ImportString *)
If[impmethod,
 body =ReadList[txtstrm,Record,endLine-startLine]; 
 bodyImport= ImportString[StringJoin[Riffle[body,"\n"]],ftype,CharacterEncoding->"UTF-8"],
(* else *)
  Which[
    ftype=="CSV", body =ReadList[txtstrm,typesval,endLine-startLine,WordSeparators->{"\n",","}],
    ftype=="TSV", body =ReadList[txtstrm,typesval,endLine-startLine,WordSeparators->{"\n","\t"}] ];    
]; (* End of If impmethod *)

(* Close the stream *)
Close[txtstrm];

(* Optionally add the header at the beginning, return the result *)
Which[
    startLine==0 && endLine==0, hdr,
    impmethod && hdrflag,   Prepend[bodyImport, hdr],
    impmethod,              bodyImport,
    hdrflag,                Prepend[body, hdr],
    True,                   body]

] (* End of readRows *)
```

#### Test

```
fname = "ExampleData/financialtimeseries.csv";

Take[Import[fname], 10] // TableForm

(* With ImportString *)
(res = readRows[financialFileName, end->10]) // TableForm
Head /@ res[[2]]

(* With default ReadLine types *)
(res = readRows[financialFileName, end->10, import->False]) // TableForm
Head /@ res[[2]]

(* With User Specified ReadLine types *)
sk[] = sk[Character];
sk[_String] = Sequence[];
mytypes = {Word, sk[], Number};

(res = readRows[financialFileName, end->10, import->False, types->mytypes]) // TableForm
Head /@ res[[2]]
```

#### Acknowledgements

- The **countLines** function is taken [from this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23579/18906) of Mr. Wizard.
- The combination of **ReadList with ImportString and Riffle** is taken [from an answer in the same post here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3891/18906) by Leonid Shifrin.
- The best part of the code, which is the **fastest reading with ReadLine based on user specified types**, is taken [from this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17874/) of Mr. Wizard. It would be great if someone analyze how exactly this blank, skipping characters work and whether I am using them appropriately here.

#### Open Source DBAPI Project

I am planning to include this in my [DBAPI project](http://healis.eu/dbapi/) so If you come up with any improvements on the code above or ideas for further enhancements please let me know.

PS1: Is it possible to improve the code so that it can parse quoted strings with embedded commas as in this file "ExampleData/TreesOwnedByTheCityOfChampaign.csv" for example ? What is going to be the types or the blanks to use in ReadLine ?

PS2: I have just fixed the FAST reading of TSV. You can specify types for ReadLine now with these files. But I have a little problem with UTF8 encoding. Characters are not displayed correctly ! Try for example to parse this stream

```
 tsvList = {{"Small", "Capital", "IntNum", "RealNum"}, {"αβ", "AB", 
5, 2.3`}, {"γδ", "CD", 1, 4.5`}, {"γδ", "CD", 6, 1.6`}, {"χψ", 
"FG", 1, 1.9`}, {"αβ", "AB", 5, 4.5`}};

 tsvString = ExportString[tsvList, "TSV", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]
```

You can turn the string to a stream and Import that works

```
 tsvStream = StringToStream@tsvString;

 Import[tsvStream, "TSV"] // TableForm
```

But I cannot find how to save this string or list expression into a file and preserve both TSV format and Unicode encoding when you read this back with e.g. Import ???

For testing purposes I have just created the file manually and assigned the filename to tsvFilename variable.

```
 (res = DBreadLines[tsvFilename, filetype -> "TSV", end -> 3, 
import -> False]) // TableForm
```

Or ReadLine with user specified types

```
(res = DBreadLines[sampleFilename, filetype -> "TSV", end -> 3, 
import -> False, types -> {Word, Word, Number, Number}]) // TableForm
```

You get an output such as

```
Small               Capital IntNum  RealNum
Î\[PlusMinus]Î\.b2  AB      5       2.3
Î\.b3Î\.b4          CD      1       4.5
Î\.b3Î\.b4          CD      6       1.6
```