# Importing hex values from a text file

Tags: import

This question appeared maybe an hour ago, but was removed by OP. I'm still interested in a solution.
Suppose we have a text file with hex numbers separated by tabs (or spaces):

```
000F    6D30    5800    4680    3790    2910    1B50    0DB0
02E0    F6F0    ED20    E7A0    E6D0    1240    3490    4E50
6700    7670    7B60    6480    5140    4120    3100    23A0
14D0    0B60    FCA0    F2D0    E990    E670    E880    20B0
3F20    56E0    6C00    7C90    72B0    5C90    4A20    3B70
2C40    1E30    1140    0500    F960    EF10    E890    E620
```

And we want to get a 2D `List` of integers.
Is there some sort of format specifier we can add to `Import`?

I tried a straightforward solution and it works, but looks over-complicated:

```
importTable[fileName_, separator_] :=
  Map[FromDigits[#, 16] &, 
     ToExpression /@ (# /. {"A" -> 10, "B" -> 11, "C" -> 12, 
           "D" -> 13, "E" -> 14, "F" -> 15}) & /@ 
      Characters /@ StringSplit[#, separator], 1] & /@ 
   Import[fileName, "Lines"];
```

Using `importTable["test.dat", WhitespaceCharacter ..]` will parse the above.

Is there a "native" way of doing it?

Comment: I think your solution can be written more simply like this: `Map[FromDigits[#, 16] &]@*StringSplit /@ Import[file, "Lines"]`

Comment: @Pickett Indeed… somehow it didn't work for me when I tried something similar

Comment: I had suggested `Map[FromDigits[#, 16] &, Import["test.dat", "Table", "Numeric" -> False], {2}]`, but the original thread got deleted.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. `"Numeric" -> False` is it documented anywhere?

Comment: In the documentation for the `"Table"` format, IIRC.

Comment: Yes, it's right there… thanks

Comment: BlacKow, it seems that none of the commenters is interested in posting a full answer. In that case, would you consider summarizing and commenting the solutions proposed by you and others in these comments into a self-answer? As you may know, those are encouraged on StackExchange, and this way the question will show up as answered to future users..

Comment: @MarcoB will do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where possible I try to use [`ReadList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html) as it is usually quite a bit faster than `Import`:

```
hex[s_String] := FromDigits[s, 16]

ReadList["test.dat", hex[Word], RecordLists -> True]
```

> ```
> {{15, 27952, 22528, 18048, 14224, 10512, 6992, 3504},
>  {736, 63216, 60704, 59296, 59088, 4672, 13456, 20048},
>  {26368, 30320, 31584, 25728, 20800, 16672, 12544, 9120},
>  {5328, 2912, 64672, 62160, 59792, 58992, 59520, 8368},
>  {16160, 22240, 27648, 31888, 29360, 23696, 18976, 15216},
>  {11328, 7728, 4416, 1280, 63840, 61200, 59536, 58912}}
> ```

For an explanation of the use of `hex[Word]` as a type see:

- [ReadList problem related to Record type](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17841/readlist-problem-related-to-record-type/17875#17875)

Also for whatever interest it may hold you could do something with string processing:

```
StringCases[
 "000F    6D30    5800    4680    3790    2910    1B50    0DB0", 
 h : HexadecimalCharacter .. :> FromDigits[h, 16]
]
```

> ```
> {15, 27952, 22528, 18048, 14224, 10512, 6992, 3504}
> ```