# Unexpected behaviour with WordSeparators and Read

Tags: import, streams, parsing

I am confused about how `Read` separates elements.

The following all work fine:

```
str = StringToStream["123 xyz 456"];
Read[str, {Number, Word, Number}, RecordSeparators -> {" ", "\t"}]
Close[str];
(* {123, "xyz", 456} *)
```

```
str = StringToStream["asd, xyz"];
Read[str, {Word, Word}, WordSeparators -> {" ", "\t", ","}]
Close[str];
(* {"asd", "xyz"} *)
```

```
str = StringToStream["123xyz"];
Read[str, Number]
Close[str];
(* 123 *)
```

Why does this not work?  And how would I handle this input with `Read`, without reading in a full line as a string and post-processing it?  Is it at all possible?

```
str = StringToStream["123, xyz, 456"];
Read[str, {Number, Word, Number}, WordSeparators -> {" ", "\t", ","}]
Close[str];

During evaluation of Read::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from StringToStream[123, xyz, 456].
(* $Failed *)
```

Comment: it seems after reading the `Word` the comma is left on the stream and throws the error.  This "works" `Read[str, {Number, Word, Character, Number},  WordSeparators -> {" ", ","}]`. Not satisfactory but it gives a clue whats happening.

Comment: @george2079 I know this issue (what you describe) has come up before.  Do you recall another question like this?

Comment: Okay, I *think* this issue is covered here: [(17841)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17841/121) but I need to re-read it to be sure.  *Edit:* Yes, it is covered there. Szabolcs, @george do you think this deserves a separate question?

Comment: I think we can call it a dup.  The short synopsis being the `Number` type does not utilize/respect  the  separator options.  You can see that just like this : `Read[StringToStream["1,2"], {Number, Number}, RecordSeparators -> {","}]`

Comment: Well I'm tentatively marking this as a duplicate as it looks like one to me.  *As always* if you disagree please let me know!