# How to efficiently read blank line separated data file into list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, import, text, data-acquisition

For example, I have a `test.dat` file with contents as below:

```
1   2
3   4
5   6

11  22
33  44
55  66
```

(Note that there could be more than two numbers in a row.)

I want to read it as

```
{{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}},{{11,22},{33,44},{55,66}}}
```

If we do

```
ReadList["test.dat",Number,RecordLists->True]
```

it is super fast, however then we loose the blank lines.

What I do now is

```
Clear[extractNumFromStr];
extractNumFromStr[string_]:=StringCases[string,x:((NumberString~~("e"|"E")~~NumberString)|NumberString):>Internal`StringToDouble@x];
file="test.dat";
DeleteCases[SplitBy[extractNumFromStr /@ ReadList[file, String, NullRecords -> True], # == {} &], {{}}]]
```

It is so awkward and is only a little faster than `Import[…, "Table"]`. Is there any neat and efficient way?

Answer (score 4):

Example file:

```
 f = OpenWrite["test00.txt"]
 Do[
  WriteString[f, 
    ExportString[RandomInteger[1000, {RandomInteger[{3, 15}], 3}], 
    "Table"] <> "\n\n"], {40}]
 Close[f]
```

`Import` method:

```
(idata = DeleteCases[
     SplitBy[Import["test00.txt", "Table"], Length], {{}}]) // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.031

Note `Import` itself is the bottleneck. It doesn't matter how you do the splitting in terms of time.

low level read method.  The trick here for efficiency is we need to also avoid using `ToExpression` . To do that we read the whole file twice.

```
 (data = Module[{f = OpenRead["test00.txt"], vals, breaks, data},
 vals = ReadList[f, ConstantArray[Number, 3]];
 SetStreamPosition[f, 1];
 breaks = 
  Join[{0}, 
   Flatten[Position[ReadList[f, Record, NullRecords -> True], 
     ""]]];
 data = 
  vals[[#[[1]] + 1 ;; #[[2]]]] & /@ 
   Partition[MapIndexed[# - (First@#2 - 1) &, breaks], 2, 1];
 Close[f]; data]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.00297188

10x faster than `Import` !

```
data == idata
```

> True

Notice we needed to know how many columns to read. This also assumes there is a single blank at the end.  You could add a check for that of course.

Comment: Oh, my god! You `ReadList` a file twice, two fast duplicate `ReadList` is still fast! this is very creative : ) +1

Comment: I would expect `ReadList[f, Number, RecordLists -> True, NullRecords -> True]` to do the whole work for us. But `NullRecords -> True` is ignored for `Number`, although `RecordLists -> True` is respected. Looks like a bug, isn't it?

Comment: I've made separate question on this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144149/280

Answer (score 2):

```
ReadList["C:\\Users\\Ali Hashmi\\Desktop\\file.dat", String, 
NullRecords -> True] // SequenceCases[#, {Except[""] ..}] & // 
ToExpression@*StringSplit /@ # &

(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{11, 22}, {33, 44}, {55, 66}}, {{22, 33, 44},
{55, 66}}, {{2, 3}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

### `ReadList`-based post-processing solution

Here is a solution which doesn't require reading the file twice (inspired by [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23579/280) answer by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard)):

```
read[s_String] := # &[ReadList[#, Number, RecordLists -> True], Close[#]] &@
   StringToStream[s];

data2 = ReadList["test00.txt", read[Record], RecordSeparators -> "\n\n"]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.276596
> ```

(the file `"test00.txt"` contains 71641 lines from which 7201 are single blank lines).

The above method ignores repeated blank lines in our input file with *blank line separated* datasets. This means that if adjacent datasets are separated by more than one blank line, we won't get an empty dataset `{}` in the resulting list. To the contrary, the [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144106/280) by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) will put empty lists `{}` between successive blank lines.

On my machine the above method is even more efficient than the [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144106/280) by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079). The following is an improved and optimized version of his solution with no assumptions about how many numbers must be on each line and with proper handling of files without blank line at the end:

```
(data = Module[{f = OpenRead["test00.txt"], vals, breaks, data, i = 0},
     vals = ReadList[f, Number, RecordLists -> True];
     SetStreamPosition[f, 1];
     breaks = 
      Flatten[{0, Position[#, ""], Length[#] + 1}] &@
       ReadList[f, Record, NullRecords -> True];
     If[breaks[[-1]] == breaks[[-2]] + 1, breaks = Most[breaks]];
     data = Table[Take[vals, {i + 1, i += n}], {n, Differences[breaks] - 1}];
     Close[f]; data]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.313066
> ```

(for efficient construction of the ragged array I used the method from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58268/280) answer by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard)).

Without repeated blank lines the results are identical:

```
data2 == data
```

> ```
> True
> ```

If the input file contains repeated blank lines, the results will be identical after removing empty lists `{}`:

```
data2 == DeleteCases[data, {}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

### String-manipulation pre-processing approach

```
(data3 = Get[#]; Close[#];) &@
   StringToStream@
    StringReplace[
     Import["test00.txt", "Text"], {StartOfString -> "{{{", "\n\n" -> "}},{{", 
      "\n" -> "},{", (" " | "\t") .. -> ",", EndOfString -> "}}}"}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.64618
> ```

```
data2 == data3 //. {} -> Nothing
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
data=Import@"C:\\ Users \\ Ali Hashmi \\ Desktop \\ file.dat";
(* {{}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {}, {11, 22}, {33, 44}, {55,66},
{}, {22, 33, 44}, {55, 66}, {}, {}, {2, 3}} *)

SequenceCases[list, pat : {{__Integer} ..} :> pat]
(* {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{11, 22}, {33, 44}, {55, 66}}, {{22, 33, 44},
{55, 66}}, {{2, 3}}} *)
```

Comment: Hi, Ali Hashmi. Thank you for answing, But `Import` is no efficient

Comment: @matheorem i do not know why `Import` is not efficient. I always thought it is optimized for handling files. Btw, check the other answer that uses `ReadList`