# Why ReadList ignores NullRecords for Number?

Tags: import, core-language, built-in-symbols, language-design, streams

When thinking on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144054/280) recent question the immediately obvious solution which came to my mind was to use `ReadList` with options `RecordLists -> True` and `NullRecords -> True` for reading objects of type `Number`. But I discovered that `NullRecords -> True` is ignored for `Number` although `RecordLists -> True` is respected:

```
ReadList[StringToStream["1 2 3\n4 5\n\n6 7\n8 9"], Number, RecordLists -> True, 
 NullRecords -> True]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}, {8, 9}}
> ```

Currently the option `NullRecords -> True` is respected only for types `Record` and `String`:

```
ReadList[StringToStream["1 2 3\n4 5\n\n6 7\n8 9"], String, RecordLists -> True, 
 NullRecords -> True]
```

> ```
> {{"1 2 3"}, {"4 5"}, {""}, {"6 7"}, {"8 9"}}
> ```

```
ReadList[StringToStream["1 2 3\n4 5\n\n6 7\n8 9"], Record, RecordLists -> True, 
 NullRecords -> True]
```

> ```
> {{"1 2 3"}, {"4 5"}, {""}, {"6 7"}, {"8 9"}}
> ```

It is interesting that in version 5.2 this option [was respected](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/IuBxa_bQ2iA/HrLaKW0zho8J) also for objects of type `Word` (but not for `Number` and `Real`):

```
$Version
ReadList[StringToStream["1 2 3\n4 5\n\n6 7\n8 9"], Word, RecordLists -> True,
  NullRecords -> True]
```

> ```
> "5.2 for Microsoft Windows x86 (64 bit) (June 20, 2005)" 
> {{"1", "2", "3"}, {"4", "5"}, {}, {"6", "7"}, {"8", "9"}}
> ```

The ignorance of `NullRecords -> True` for `Number` makes no sense for me, especially considering that `RecordLists -> True` is respected. Is there any reason for this? Is it a bug?

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17875/2079