# Reading specific entries from a CSV file

Tags: import, csv-format

This question is related to the following:

[Speeding up Import and Export in CSV format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35371/speeding-up-import-and-export-in-csv-format)

[Stream CSV or TSV files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/stream-csv-files/3891#3891)

[Reading periodic elements from a large file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/reading-periodic-elements-from-a-large-file)

I have a set of very large CSV files (a few hundred MB), [a sample file is available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0gdokvdl7qt0jg/Test.csv.zip). RAM limitations make it quite cumbersome to use Import.

I am only interested in a subset of data from the file:

- I want to read data from just a few columns
- I want to read data from every 256th row starting with the 3rd row

```
 columns = {3, 4, 5, 8, 12}; first = 3; step = 256;
```

I am interested in methods that minimize memory and speed up import.

Comment: Have you tried some of the solutions in the linked questions? At first glance your research seems spot-on.

Comment: I did try a few things. I can’t figure out how to skip rows. Adding a Take function to the readRows functions in the Stream CSV file example is slowing things down…

Comment: There is, in fact, a function exactly for skipping records in a stream: its name is... [Skip](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Skip.html)!

Comment: For a generic type of answer on this problem you may read my solution [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107666/18906).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Previous Answers Below**

Here is a more general approach but somewhat slower on my machine:

```
readSkipCSVGen[file_String?FileExistsQ, first_Integer, step_Integer, cols_: {3, 4, 5, 8, 12}] := 
 Module[{str = OpenRead[file], temp, data, ta}, 
  Skip[str, String, first - 1];
  data = Reap[
     While[
      Or[ta =!= EndOfFile, Not@ValueQ[ta]],
      Sow[temp = Read[str, String]];
      Skip[str, String, step - 2];
      ta = Read[str, String];
      ]
     ][[2, 1]];
  Close[str];
  ToExpression[StringCases[data, NumberString]][[All, cols]]
  ]
```

Then:

```
lis = readSkipCSVGen["filename.csv", 3, 256]
```

For a different set of columns e.g `{3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 13}`. Note that the columns do not have to be in order.

```
lis2 = readSkipCSVGen["filename.csv", 3, 256, {3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 6, 13}];

lis2[[1 ;; 5]]

{{-8.44531, 0.32031, -0.080078, 22, 32, 0.007568,  0.19870377},
 {-8.47656, 0.26562, -0.080078, 22, 32, 0.007568,  0.19870377},
 {-8.48438, 0.29688, -0.080078, 22, 32, 0.007324,  0.19870377},
 {-8.46094, 0.3125, -0.080322, 22, 32, 0.007568,   0.19870377},
 {-8.45312, 0.28906, -0.080322, 22, 32, 0.007324,  0.19870377}}
```

**Original Answer**

Here is an answer tailored for your problem. I make no attempt to generalize this. I may add that in the future but for now this does what you want and is plenty fast.

```
readSkipCSV[file_String?FileExistsQ, first_Integer, step_Integer] := 
 Module[{str = OpenRead[file], data = {}, temp, ta},
  Skip[str, String, first - 2];
  ta = Read[str, String];
  While[ta =!= EndOfFile,
    Skip[str, Word, 2, WordSeparators -> {","}];
    temp = Read[str, Table[Word, {3}], WordSeparators -> {","}]; 
    Skip[str, Word, 2, WordSeparators -> {","}];
    temp = {temp, Read[str, Word, WordSeparators -> {","}]};
    Skip[str, Word, 3, WordSeparators -> {","}];
    temp = {temp, Read[str, Word, WordSeparators -> {","}]};
    Skip[str, String];
    data = {data, temp};
    Skip[str, String, step - 2];
    ta = Read[str, String];
    ]
   Close[str]; Partition[ToExpression[Flatten @ data], 5]
  ]
```

**Usage**

```
lis = readSkipCSV["filename.csv", 3, 256]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.162101, Null}

```
lis[[1 ;; 10]]

{{-8.44531, -3.0625, 0.32031, 0.929932, 0.421932219}, 
 {-8.47656, -3.03906, 0.26562, 0.929688, 0.421932219},
 {-8.48438, -3.01562, 0.29688, 0.929688, 0.421932219}, 
 {-8.46094, -3.04688, 0.3125, 0.930176, 0.421932219}, 
 {-8.45312, -3.03125, 0.28906, 0.929932, 0.421932219},
 {-8.42969, -3.0625, 0.30469, 0.929688, 0.421932219},
 {-8.42188, -3.02344, 0.27344, 0.929932, 0.421932219},
 {-8.44531, -3.07031, 0.29688, 0.929443, 0.421932219},
 {-8.42969, -3.03906, 0.27344, 0.929932, 0.421937941},
 {-8.42188, -3.0625, 0.29688, 0.929932, 0.421937941}}
```

Number of lines read:

```
Length @ lis
```

> 4096

This is from reading your ~255MB file

*Edit*

You can also use `Reap` and `Sow` in addition to `AppendTo` which avoids `Flatten`ing the data and `Partition`ing it afterwards.

```
readSkipCSVSow[file_String?FileExistsQ, first_Integer, step_Integer] :=
 Module[{str = OpenRead[file], temp, data, ta},
      Skip[str, String, first - 1];
      data = Reap[
                 While[Or[ta =!= EndOfFile, Not@ValueQ[ta]],
                 Skip[str, Word, 2, WordSeparators -> {","}];
                 temp = Read[str, Table[Word, {3}], WordSeparators -> {","}]; 
                 Skip[str, Word, 2, WordSeparators -> {","}];
                 temp = AppendTo[temp, Read[str, Word, WordSeparators -> {","}]];
                 Skip[str, Word, 3, WordSeparators -> {","}];
                 temp = AppendTo[temp, Read[str, Word, WordSeparators -> {","}]];
                 Skip[str, String];
                 Sow[temp];
                 Skip[str, String, step - 2];
                 ta = Read[str, String];
                 ]
              ][[2, 1]];
      Close[str]; ToExpression[data]
     ]
```

Usage is the same as before.

Comment: 2runnyKine: thanks. I have been working on a solution. Will post it for completeness, not as fast as yours…

Comment: @Pam. Glad I could help.

Comment: If performance is an issue it *might be* faster to make all of the `Read`ing and `Skip`ing whole lines (`String`), then extract the columns you need from the strings.

Comment: @george2079, I actually did that but didn't post that version. Because of the hassle involved in dealing with the `String` returned when reading .csv files, it turned out to be slightly slower but more general than the answer I posted. I'll probably just put that up for completeness.

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you are doing there: I am a bit lost why the solutions get so complicated. Perhaps you understand this puzzle [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65377/import-csv-data-with-header-of-many-rows-having-unique-identifier-on-rows-1-2) better than me?